# Loop through multidimensional array with childrens and build map of paths

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

**I have the multidimensional array with childrens (subcategories)**:

I build Angular routing and get this data format from API.

```js
const items = [{
  displayName: 'Wiadomości',
  urlName: 'wiadomosci',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Newsy',
    urlName: 'newsy',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Wydarzenia',
    urlName: 'wydarzenia',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Komentarze i analizy',
    urlName: 'komentarze-i-analizy',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Reportaże',
    urlName: 'reportaze',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Prawo',
  urlName: 'prawo',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Sprzedaż/zakup',
    urlName: 'sprzedaz-zakup',
    subcategories: [{
      displayName: 'Dom',
      urlName: 'dom',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Mieszkanie',
      urlName: 'mieszkanie',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Działka',
      urlName: 'dzialka',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Komercyjne',
      urlName: 'komercyjne',
      subcategories: []
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Najem/dzierżawa',
    urlName: 'najem-dzierzawa',
    subcategories: [{
      displayName: 'Dom',
      urlName: 'dom',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Mieszkanie',
      urlName: 'mieszkanie',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Prywatny/komercyjny',
      urlName: 'prywatny-komercyjny',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Działka',
      urlName: 'dzialka',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Budynki',
      urlName: 'budynki',
      subcategories: []
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Podatki',
    urlName: 'podatki',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Prawo budowlane',
    urlName: 'prawo-budowlane',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Dziedziczenie',
    urlName: 'dziedziczenie',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Wzory dokumentów',
    urlName: 'wzory-dokumentow',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Finanse',
  urlName: 'finanse',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Kredyty',
    urlName: 'kredyty',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Ubezpieczenia',
    urlName: 'ubezpieczenia',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Kalkulatory',
    urlName: 'kalkulatory',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Inwestycje',
    urlName: 'inwestycje',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Dofinansowanie i dotacje',
    urlName: 'dofinansowanie-i-dotacje',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Porady i inspiracje',
  urlName: 'porady-i-inspiracje',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Budowa i remont',
    urlName: 'budowa-i-remont',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Użytkowanie',
    urlName: 'uzytkowanie',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Balkon i ogród',
    urlName: 'balkon-i-ogrod',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Aranżacje',
    urlName: 'aranzacje',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Design',
    urlName: 'design',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Eksperci',
  urlName: 'eksperci',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Felietony',
    urlName: 'felietony',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Zapytaj eksperta',
    urlName: 'zapytaj-eksperta',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Materiały źródłowe',
    urlName: 'materialy-zrodlowe',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}];
```

I absolutely need to map the response from the server to an array that contains paths built from subcategories and urlName.

**The output should be:**

```js
const paths = [
   'wiadomosci',
   'wiadomosci/newsy'
   'wiadomosci/komentarze-i-analizy',
   'wiadomosci/reportaze',
   'prawo',
   'prawo/sprzedaz-zakup',
   'prawo/sprzedaz-zakup/dom',
   'prawo/sprzedaz-zakup/mieszkanie',
   'prawo/sprzedaz-zakup/dzialka',
   'prawo/sprzedaz-zakup/komercyjne',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa/dom',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa/mieszkanie',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa/prywatny-komercyjny',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa/dzialka',
   'prawo/najem-dzierzawa/budynki',
   'podatki',
   'prawo-budowlane',
   'dziedziczenie',
   'wzory-dokumentow',
   'finanse',
   'finanse/kredyty',
   'finanse/ubezpieczenia',
   'finanse/kalkulatory',
   'finanse/inwestycje',
   'finanse/dofinansowanie-i-dotacje',
   'porady-i-inspiracje',
   'porady-i-inspiracje/budowa-i-remont',
   'porady-i-inspiracje/uzytkowanie',
   'porady-i-inspiracje/balkon-i-ogrod',
   'porady-i-inspiracje/aranzacje',
   'porady-i-inspiracje/design',
   'eksperci',
   'eksperci/felietony',
   'eksperci/zapytaj-eksperta',
   'eksperci/materialy-zrodlowe'
];
```

I have tried to write recursive functions that will collect and build paths for me, but unfortunately I fail ...

Can you help me with this? :/

My try in PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2c4fc7dbddd226d0ec09e7ac020adc2d3c1d6dc

Comment: please add your try. where do you get `/1` from?

Comment: why do you send the second level subcategories from the server if it's always empty? Would that play a role in the answer?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I removed numbers now. My try in PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2c4fc7dbddd226d0ec09e7ac020adc2d3c1d6dc

Comment: @EugenSunic: I think that no. My try in PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2c4fc7dbddd226d0ec09e7ac020adc2d3c1d6dc

Comment: You have tagged this "PHP", "Javascript", and "Typescript"; which are you working in? Please also [edit] your question to include a [mcve] **in the question itself** (so that we don't have to click through to see it, and the question will still be useful to others if the page you linked to changes or goes away). Remember to include a _short_ sample input, the output you currently get, and the output you want _for that specific input_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a compact approach by mapping the nested pathes by taking a prefix for all nested objects.

```js
const
    items = [{ displayName: 'Wiadomości', urlName: 'wiadomosci', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Newsy', urlName: 'newsy', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Wydarzenia', urlName: 'wydarzenia', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Komentarze i analizy', urlName: 'komentarze-i-analizy', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Reportaże', urlName: 'reportaze', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Prawo', urlName: 'prawo', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Sprzedaż/zakup', urlName: 'sprzedaz-zakup', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Dom', urlName: 'dom', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Mieszkanie', urlName: 'mieszkanie', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Działka', urlName: 'dzialka', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Komercyjne', urlName: 'komercyjne', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Najem/dzierżawa', urlName: 'najem-dzierzawa', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Dom', urlName: 'dom', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Mieszkanie', urlName: 'mieszkanie', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Prywatny/komercyjny', urlName: 'prywatny-komercyjny', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Działka', urlName: 'dzialka', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Budynki', urlName: 'budynki', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Podatki', urlName: 'podatki', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Prawo budowlane', urlName: 'prawo-budowlane', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Dziedziczenie', urlName: 'dziedziczenie', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Wzory dokumentów', urlName: 'wzory-dokumentow', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Finanse', urlName: 'finanse', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Kredyty', urlName: 'kredyty', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Ubezpieczenia', urlName: 'ubezpieczenia', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Kalkulatory', urlName: 'kalkulatory', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Inwestycje', urlName: 'inwestycje', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Dofinansowanie i dotacje', urlName: 'dofinansowanie-i-dotacje', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Porady i inspiracje', urlName: 'porady-i-inspiracje', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Budowa i remont', urlName: 'budowa-i-remont', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Użytkowanie', urlName: 'uzytkowanie', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Balkon i ogród', urlName: 'balkon-i-ogrod', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Aranżacje', urlName: 'aranzacje', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Design', urlName: 'design', subcategories: [] }] }, { displayName: 'Eksperci', urlName: 'eksperci', subcategories: [{ displayName: 'Felietony', urlName: 'felietony', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Zapytaj eksperta', urlName: 'zapytaj-eksperta', subcategories: [] }, { displayName: 'Materiały źródłowe', urlName: 'materialy-zrodlowe', subcategories: [] }] }],
    getPath = prefix => ({ urlName, subcategories }) =>
        (path => [path, ...subcategories.flatMap(getPath(path))])
        (prefix + (prefix && '/') + urlName),
    paths = items.flatMap(getPath(''));

console.log(paths);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Loop through your items, the inside collect the children, return the first parent item without the slash and the children together

```js
const items = [{
  displayName: 'Wiadomości',
  urlName: 'wiadomosci',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Newsy',
    urlName: 'newsy',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Wydarzenia',
    urlName: 'wydarzenia',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Komentarze i analizy',
    urlName: 'komentarze-i-analizy',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Reportaże',
    urlName: 'reportaze',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Prawo',
  urlName: 'prawo',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Sprzedaż/zakup',
    urlName: 'sprzedaz-zakup',
    subcategories: [{
      displayName: 'Dom',
      urlName: 'dom',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Mieszkanie',
      urlName: 'mieszkanie',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Działka',
      urlName: 'dzialka',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Komercyjne',
      urlName: 'komercyjne',
      subcategories: []
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Najem/dzierżawa',
    urlName: 'najem-dzierzawa',
    subcategories: [{
      displayName: 'Dom',
      urlName: 'dom',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Mieszkanie',
      urlName: 'mieszkanie',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Prywatny/komercyjny',
      urlName: 'prywatny-komercyjny',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Działka',
      urlName: 'dzialka',
      subcategories: []
    }, {
      displayName: 'Budynki',
      urlName: 'budynki',
      subcategories: []
    }]
  }, {
    displayName: 'Podatki',
    urlName: 'podatki',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Prawo budowlane',
    urlName: 'prawo-budowlane',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Dziedziczenie',
    urlName: 'dziedziczenie',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Wzory dokumentów',
    urlName: 'wzory-dokumentow',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Finanse',
  urlName: 'finanse',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Kredyty',
    urlName: 'kredyty',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Ubezpieczenia',
    urlName: 'ubezpieczenia',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Kalkulatory',
    urlName: 'kalkulatory',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Inwestycje',
    urlName: 'inwestycje',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Dofinansowanie i dotacje',
    urlName: 'dofinansowanie-i-dotacje',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Porady i inspiracje',
  urlName: 'porady-i-inspiracje',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Budowa i remont',
    urlName: 'budowa-i-remont',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Użytkowanie',
    urlName: 'uzytkowanie',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Balkon i ogród',
    urlName: 'balkon-i-ogrod',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Aranżacje',
    urlName: 'aranzacje',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Design',
    urlName: 'design',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}, {
  displayName: 'Eksperci',
  urlName: 'eksperci',
  subcategories: [{
    displayName: 'Felietony',
    urlName: 'felietony',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Zapytaj eksperta',
    urlName: 'zapytaj-eksperta',
    subcategories: []
  }, {
    displayName: 'Materiały źródłowe',
    urlName: 'materialy-zrodlowe',
    subcategories: []
  }]
}];


const result = items.reduce((acc, x) => {
  list = x.subcategories.reduce((acc2, y) => {
    acc2.push(x.displayName.toLowerCase() + '/' + y.urlName.toLowerCase())
    return acc2
  }, []);
  acc.push([x.displayName.toLowerCase(), ...list]);
  return acc;
}, []).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Kudos on the eloquent reducer! I think OP needs `urlName` instead of `displayName` at the top level though.